# How to shift columns in a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, shift

I would like to substract every column in my Dataframe by the column next to it, like this:

```
for l in list:
    df[l] = df[l].sub(df[l].shift(axis = 1))
```

It does work with `axis = 0`, but not with `axis = 1`. And I don't know why. Any idea?

Comment: did you try to remove `for` loop? `df -= df.shift(axis=1)`

Comment: Yes, it works outside the loop, but not in the loop

Comment: In the loop you are operating a column which only has one axis

Comment: Oh, yeah, you're right. Thanks!